# How is it possible to get the largest member of template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

My struct is defined like this:

```cpp
template<class...T> struct Data {};
```

How is it possible to get the maximum of `sizeof(T)`, so it can be used inside `struct Data`?

Comment: Evg has a good answer. But what do you want to do with the max? Allocate an array?
Because then you could use std::array<T,sizeof(T)...> as datamember

Answer (score 10):

If you need the largest size, the solution is pretty straightforward: use [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) overload that takes `std::initializer_list`. It is `constexpr` since C++14.

```
constexpr std::size_t max_size = std::max({sizeof(T)...});
```

To handle an empty pack you might add the `0` argument:

```
constexpr std::size_t max_size = std::max({0, sizeof(T)...});
```

---

If the type itself is needed and Boost can be used, [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) might help:

```
namespace mp11 = boost::mp11;

template<class T1, class T2>
struct less_sizeof : mp11::mp_bool<(sizeof(T1) < sizeof(T2))> {};

using Tm = mp11::mp_max_element<mp11::mp_list<T...>, less_sizeof>;
```

---

If Boost is not available, some simple metaprogramming could be used:

```
template<class T, class... U>
struct max_sizeof {
    using Tm = typename max_sizeof<U...>::type;
    using type = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(Tm) < sizeof(T)), T, Tm>;
};

template<class T>
struct max_sizeof<T> {
    using type = T;
};

using Tm = typename max_sizeof<Ts...>::type;
```

In both cases a tie is resolved to the last type with the largest `sizeof(T)`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the actual type (well, the first type that has the maximum size) then it can be pretty compact in C++17 and beyond:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

template<class...T> struct Data {

    static constexpr std::size_t biggest_idx() {
        std::size_t const sizes[] { sizeof(T) ... };
        return std::max_element(std::begin(sizes), std::end(sizes)) - std::begin(sizes);
    }
    
    using biggest = std::tuple_element_t<biggest_idx(), std::tuple<T...>>;
};
```

Just find the index in a constexpr utility (with the `constexpr max_element`), and then use the `std::tuple` facilitates to obtain the type.

If you don't like using `std::tuple` here, then you can roll your own meta-function of course. Pretty straight-forward. You can also write the loop for finding the maximum index by hand if you only have C++14.

Answer (score 4):

Works for >= C++14 (assuming you want the type with the largest size and not the largest size itself):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct largest_type
{
    using type = typename std::conditional<
        sizeof (T) == std::max({sizeof (T), sizeof (Ts)...}),
        T,
        typename largest_type<Ts...>::type
    >::type;
};

template <typename T>
struct largest_type<T>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
using largest_type_t = typename largest_type<T, Ts...>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<largest_type_t<int, char, long>, long>::value, "");
```

Comment: I've simplified your solution a little bit: https://godbolt.org/z/c1Mr5jG9f

Comment: @Evg yep, that's definitely a better solution. If you change your `std::conditional_t` to `typename std::conditional<>::type`, it would even work with C++11!